# Suggestion - `NOT` inverted searches

Tags: feature-request, search

Not sure if this is possible and I just didn't read well enough but a `not` operator in search might be helpful.

For Example:

`[android] studio is:question ![android-studio]`
To exclude questions with the tag `android-studio` but with results with `studio` in the body

`[android] android studio is:question ![android-studio]`
or to find questions about android studio but without the correct tag.

Comment: Does the `-` operator provide the functionality you seek? [Example search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+studio+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bandroid-studio%5D)

Comment: Thanks! Would be nice if it was part of the `Advanced Search Tips`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already implemented in SE sites. You can use `-` symbol for this.

Just try with: `[android] studio is:question -[android-studio]`